# Unwrapping a brick / rough rectangle object on marked seams?

Tags: uv, sculpting

So I created this brick with sculpt and then went into edit mode, selected a rough cube of edges and marked them as seams. Unfortunately with no method of unwrapping those seams are giving me a SIMPLE 6 sided UV map (albeit with rough edges). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "6 sided UVmap"? Something like this: http://imgur.com/FxPGg3Q?